# header and footer elements must be inside the .container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Keeping HTML 5 elements header and footer inside the .container div of bootstrap is a good practice?

Except setting padding externally when we place out of .container, it is working both ways just want to know which is the good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice is to have

- `<header>`
- `<main>`
- `<footer>`

as **top-level elements** inside the `<body>` of the HTML document.

Additionally, you might also want to have

- `<nav>` (principal navigation)
- `<aside>` (sidebar)

as **top-level elements** inside the `<body>` of the HTML document.

Of course, this is not the only good practice - this is simply one example of good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Not Strictly,

Yes, you can put the header tag inside a div tag, but there are some contextual semantics that are implied by embedding the header under elements other than the body. Depending on how you structure the document, you may run into unexpected behaviors.

The good practice is to put header tag inside body tag.

Answer (score 0):

.container div measures in width...so putting header and footer in .container div is good for practice..